# Intercepting Hyperlink Clicks After jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, load, click, href

What's the technique to intercept hyperlink clicks after they are loaded via a jQuery .load()?

I have a jQuery .load() that's pulling back some hyperlinks that act as "buttons", which look like this:

```
<a class="button" href="" onclick="install('test1');return false;">Install Test1</a>
<a class="button" href="" onclick="install('test2');return false;">Install Test2</a>
```

The trouble I'm having is that the href is firing instead of the onclick handler.

Of course, I tried doing this differently with jQuery's live() function on the 'click' event, but the href is firing instead.

Comment: Be aware -- I've been up coding for like 18 hours straight. So, if Captain Obvious comes here and shows me a foolish mistake, I won't be surprised. LOL. (I'm heading off to sleep now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Of course, I tried doing this differently with jQuery's live() function on the 'click' event, but the href is firing instead." - well that is the way it should be done, and it's proven to work, so I guess

- you do not execute the live bindings from your document ready
- your selector for the bindings is not correct
- you don't return false from your live() function, so event delegation continues

Any of the above would result in 'firing' the hrefs.

Comment: Here's what I found. I was passing an onclick="nothing" and then trying to overwrite that after the .load() call by doing .attr('onclick','install("test1");return false;'). But the thing I found out was that jQuery won't let you overwrite the onclick attribute after a .load() event. And since a "nothing" function didn't exist, it fired the href value. The fix was to use .data() to store what I needed, and then use .live() to capture the click, read .data(), and process it.

Comment: @Volomike: I think that part: "jQuery won't let you overwrite the onclick attribute after a .load() event" is not true. I rather suspect that jQuery did all the bindings it was told to do, and the first bind was to a nonexistent function called "nothing" that - of course - returned nothing, so your href was activated. Anyways, I'm glad it worked out for you ;)

Comment: ás, yeah, didn't make sense to me either. I still don't know why the onclick attribute couldn't be overwritten in my code. Other attributes got overwritten, just not that one.